# Prove that if $G$ is a finite simple group containing a subgroup $H$ of order $27$, then $|G : H| \ge 9.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof, simple-groups

> Prove that if $G$ is a finite simple group containing a subgroup $H$ of order $27$, then $|G : H| \ge 9.$

I have so far been solving this by looking at $|G:N|=1, 2, 3...$ etc., all the way up to $8$ and showing that each case is not possible. This is a method that I believe will work in solving the problem if I continue using it (I have shown it does not work for $1, 2$, and $3$).

However, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about a problem like this.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $|S_8| = 8!$ is not divisible by $27$, so $G$ cannot be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ for $n<9$.

Comment: Ahh, yes! Thank you! That is much simpler than what I was trying.

Comment: @DerekHolt, isn't $n=9$ ruled out either, being $27\cdot 9 \nmid 9!$?

Comment: @rhesu Yes you are right! I guess asking to prove $|G:H|>9$ would have made the problem slightly harder.

Comment: Of course it's not hard to rule out $|G:H|=10$, $|G:H|=11$, etc. The smallest example I can think of is ${\rm PSL}(3,3)$, where the index is $208$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|G:H|<9$, then since  $G$ is a simple group, it is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_8$. But the group $S_8$ has a Sylow $3$-subgroup of  order $9.$ We have a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient $G/H$. If $G$ is simple, then $G$ embeds into $S_{[G:H]}$ and hence $|G|$ divides $[G:H]!$. But $|G|=27[G:H]$, so $|G|$ divides $[G:H]!$ if and only if $3^3 \mid ([G:H]-1)!$ if and only if $[G:H]\ge 10$. Therefore, a stronger condition holds, actually.